# scrollTop = scrollHeight not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I'm using *divRef.current.scrollTop = divRef.current.scrollHeight* in my react application to scroll to end of the scrollable div. it's working as expected in chrome but it's not working on safari.

```
divRef.current.scrollTop = divRef.current.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this line also:

`divRef.current.scrollIntoView(false);`

Answer (score 0):

yeah it works but , the options are not supported in safari for scrollIntoView
so the scroll will be without any animation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29937624)